# Inform User Account Exists

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, client

On my application, I have standard email authentication, as well as two oauth services (say Google and Facebook)

If a user has signed up with Facebook, but then they try to log in through regular email authentication, should I tell them to use Facebook?

At first, I thought this was straightforward, but realized this might have potential security ramifications.

What do you all think?

(Also, is this fine to ask on Stack Overflow, or should I repost to Software Engineering?)

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that a user has disabled the Facebook (or some other service's) option to be looked up by his/her e-mail. Therefore, it is probably not a good solution to give a message that suggests to log-in via Facebook, because an attacker can get information that the user has marked as private.

What I would do is, I would change the message shown when a user does not exist to something along the lines of "Invalid user (if you have already signed up using some other service (e.g. Facebook), please log-in using that service)". I would present this message both to users that do not exist, and to users who have signed up using some service. This way an attacker cannot distinguish between a user who has not signed up and a user who signed up using some service, while the legitimate user is getting a hint of what might be wrong. I believe that some usability problems will come up, but this way the privacy of the users is much better respected.